# php alternative to Application_Start in c#

Tags: php

I am used to using application_start event in c# in glocal.ascx.

I need to create something similar in php so when the application first loads i can cache all data first time round.

Does anyone know a good way of me doing this.

Comment: Raw PHP isn't a framework as such so you'll have to do this manually, or consider using a framework like FuelPHP

Comment: just use the destructor of your classes to cache anything once you are round the first time. and load the cache in the constructor you come around the second time ;)

Answer (score 1):

PHP does not have something like an AppDomain in ASP.NET.

In ASP.NET the webserver spawns once an AppDomain process and (synchronous) requests are handled as "HttpContext threads" inside this process. Asynchronous IHttpHandlers may be handled over multiple threads, but are also sharing the same AppDomain process.

In PHP each request is a single process (as of FastCGI a thread), but you don't have a static shared scope. A script executes and then dies. To share data in-memory, you need helpers like memcache.

Answer (score 0):

In php each script sequentially runs through all code and then dies.  So, if I understand your question properly you basically want to build the caching system into the top of your script.

On my simpler projects I simply include a file (I called it assign.inc) which handles all my site wide/global tasks.  It loads first on every page and sets up my session/db connection etc.

On my bigger projects I wrote all traffic through index.php (via .htaccess) this initiates my CMS class which does everything though __construct.

Does that help?